# scipy stats skewness is not correctly provide skewness results

Tags: scipy, statistics

I noticed that the skewness returned from scipy stats is not correct. Pandas.skew() actually provide better results. 
I am recently trying to duplicate a classic paper, Expected Stock Returns and Volatility by French&Schwert. I use S&P500 data from 1928 to 1984. I follow the formula in the paper for standard deviation of the return and I am able to get the same result for mean, std dev of std dev. 
However, when I use scipy.stats.skew function, I can't not get any number of the std dev of the sp return. The function return "nan", where clearly it should return a value. 
I switch to Pandas.skew(). it returned me the correct value as in the paper.

Clearly, something is wrong with the scipy.stats.skew() function.

scipy.stats.skew()
pandas.skew()

1. Results by Scipy.stats.skew()
   ['Adj Close_gspc', 'Adj Close_gspc_lag', 'SP_Return', 'SP_Return_square',
      'SP_Return_lag', 'SP_varianceMon', 'SP_varianceMon_sqrRoot']

array([ 0.6922229 ,  0.69186265, -0.11292165,  4.23571807, -1.9556035 ,
        5.39873607,         nan])

2. results by pandas:

Adj Close_gspc            0.693745
Adj Close_gspc_lag        0.693384
SP_Return                -0.113170
SP_Return_square          4.245033
SP_Return_lag            -1.959904
SP_varianceMon            5.410609
SP_varianceMon_sqrRoot    2.800919
dtype: float64

Comment: It would be easier to help you debug the `nan` value if you provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can run to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information or sample code to reproduce the `nan` that you get.

To make `scipy.stats.skew` compute the same value as the `skew()` method in Pandas, add the argument `bias=False`.

Here's an example.

First, the imports:

```
In [21]: import numpy as np                                                                      

In [22]: import pandas as pd                                                                     

In [23]: from scipy.stats import skew
```

Generate some data:

```
In [24]: np.random.seed(8675309)                                                                 

In [25]: x = np.random.weibull(0.2, size=15)
```

Compute the skew with scipy and with Pandas:

```
In [26]: skew(x, bias=False)                                                                     
Out[26]: 3.7582525674514544

In [27]: pd.Series(x).skew()                                                                     
Out[27]: 3.7582525674514544
```